# If category has image then show if not don't

Tags: category, magento-1, image, media-images

I want my categories to have the image above the content and the left column, whilst using 2columns-left.phtml and don't want an image placeholder showing if there's no image. So I need an if statement but not sure how to go about it!

Here's my code so far

```
<?php $categoryImage = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getImage(); //Get the file name of the Image stored for the category ?>

<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$categoryImage  ?>" />
```

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an if statement to check for `$categoryImage` value.

Here's a better way to do it (basically you let Magento create the full URL)

```
$helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$category  = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()

if ($imgUrl = $category->getImageUrl()) {
    $imgHtml = '<img src="'.$imgUrl.'" alt="' . $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) . '" title="' . $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) . '" />';
    echo $helper->categoryAttribute($category, $imgHtml, 'image');
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much. I have also tried to upvote the answer but my reputation isn't high enough!